# Why this jQuery dialog code is not working? Everything seems just fine

Tags: html, jquery, dialog

I am trying to show a jQuery dialog. My intention is to create a form inside the dialog, but I am not even getting it to appear. Anybody has any idea? This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wrapper").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Basic Dialog'
  });

$("#budget").click(function(){
  $("#wrapper").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
});
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
<p>Name:</p>
</div>

<!-- JQUERY CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4./jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery has no dialog method. jQuery UI does though. Did you remember to include it? What errors do you get in your console?

Comment: Hi, I have not opened the log.console yet. But I thought this was from jQuery. Can you tell me how to include jQuery UI. I am almost sure that must be the problem. Thanks.